# append query failed key violation

Tags: sql, append

My append query fails due to key violation but only one new records, the old records append normally just the new ones that I added fail.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Order_Item] ([Order_ID],[Item_ID],[Quantity]) Values (" & orderNumber & ", [Enter Item ID], [Enter Quantity])"
```

Order_ID and Item_ID are foreign keys

Comment: Key violation would indicate you are trying to insert a primary key which is already in use. Foreign keys don't matter. Check your primary key values

Comment: What does your table structure look like? Do you have a unique (auto-incrementing) key field? Or what does your primary key look like? Is the combination trying to add already in there (so it really IS a key violation)

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You're practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Do both the id values exist in their respective tables?

Comment: if i ignore the message box then it updates primary key but other attributes are empty, primary key is auto-incrementing, the rest are numbers-long, i dont care about sql injection attacks this is my first semester in access/sql, and the values do exsist, it only doesnt work for new tables that i have added, i can post my project and if someone would care to look at it, please do i have spent 3 hours trying to figure it out

Comment: @BigApeWhat I have tested this in access and can recreate a similar error, do check that the id's you are inserting are in both tables. Access will raise and error re key violation when you insert something into the FK via sql that isn't in the related table.

Comment: OMFG i cant believe i missed that, i was taking the wrong value for Order Number, it worked for the old tables because the Order Number = Order Id, but the new tables have a gap so Order Number = 20 and Order Id = 8

Answer (score 0):

Access will raise an error re. key violation when you insert something into the FK via sql that isn't in the related table. You may also get a similar error for primary key violations.

Here is some code (which you'd need to adapt to your model) to check the keys exists in the related tables and that the 'mapping' does not already exist in the mapping table before you insert.

```
Select Case True

    Case IsNull(DLookup("[ID]", "Table1", "[ID]=" & num1))
        MsgBox ("ID does not exist in Table1")

    Case IsNull(DLookup("[ID]", "Table2", "[ID]=" & num2))
        MsgBox ("ID does not exist in Table2")

    Case Not (IsNull(DLookup("[ID1]", "Map", "[ID1]=" & num1 & "And [ID2]=" & num2)))
        MsgBox ("Mapping already exists")

    Case Else
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Map] VALUES (" & num1 & ", " & num2 & ")"

End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved a similar issue that was caused by a key violation issue. Two lessons that I learned might be helpful to others with similar issues:

1. make sure that your relationships diagram shows every table - I didn't (and the non-visible table was linked to a visible one, and that was the problem link). It's too easy to forget the links you've set up!
2. if you're not sure which field in the query is driving the key violation error, type a valid value into a blank field on the table - if it's the field causing the problem it'll tell you which field needs a related entry.

Of course be extra vigilant if this is a "live" system and remove any "test" data!